# Osmosis OpenStreetMap (OSM) filter nodes and their ways and relations to location

Tags: openstreetmap, osmosis

Using [osmosis](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/w/index.php?title=Osmosis/Detailed_Usage), how can one filter nodes with specific key and its associated location?

For example, executing

```bash
osmosis --read-pbf myregion.pbf --write-xml highway.osm --node-key keyList="highway"
```

yields a file named `highway.osm` that holds all `highway` nodes where each [node has the attributes `lat="..." lon="..."`](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Node).

Is there a way to get the node location by name, rather than lat/lon coordinates, from `myregion.pbf` without implementing a lat/lon to continent/country/city lookup.

For instance, for the node of "New Jersey Turnpike Newark Bay Ext" highway, how to obtain all the following: America/USA/New-York?